# Why does $scope.$watch work but $scope.$watchCollection does not?

Tags: angularjs

I tried using the `$scope.$watchCollection()` method on an array that I need to watch for changes in order to run some filtering on.  When the user uses checkboxes and a button to toggle a boolean value on  1 or more of these objects in the given array, the $watch is not being triggered appropriately. However, changing the `$watchCollection` to a `$scope.$watch(arr, function(){}, true)` with objectEquality flag set to true causes the $watch to work just fine. Why would the `$watchCollection` not automatically use objectEquality to determine if changes were made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchCollection) of `$scope.$watchCollection` :

> Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of
>   the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array
>   items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties). If a
>   change is detected, the listener callback is fired.

So for an `Array` it will perform a **shallow** watch on the items of the `Array`, which in your case means that the watch function will get triggered if you add or remove items from the `Array`. If you have an `Array` of objects, Angular won't perform a deep `$watch` on those objects.

As @GregL has pointed out in the comment bellow: the point of `$scope.$watchCollection` is to be able to do a `shallow` `$watch` on an `Object` or an `Array`, since a deep `$watch` is much more expensive, although sometimes it's needed.

The only thing that I would add to @GregL's comment is that very often we forget that the `watchExpression` of the `$watch` function (the first parameter) can also be function that can be used for tracking the changes of a very concrete part of a large `Object` or `Array`, there are many cases when we could write that function instead of using a deep `$watch`, which would make the `$watch` much more efficient.

Comment: As I understand it, the whole point of `$watchCollection` is that it is more efficient than doing a deep `$watch`. When you consider that for a deep watch, the most computationally expensive path is when the two objects are different but exactly equal, and it has to traverse every single property, you start to see why deep watches are so expensive and should be avoided where possible. But if you need to use them, a deep watch is the ultimate way to check if something has changed anywhere within a scope value.

Comment: @GregL if you are ok with it I will add your comment to the answer and I will also add a bit more to it.

Comment: @GregL I just updated my answer, please have a look at it and let me know what you think, thanks a lot for your feedback!

Comment: I approve of your additional comments, that is a great technique to keep in mind.