# watchCollection on ng-model does not fire when checkbox is toggled

Tags: angularjs

When I click the checkbox, the `$scope.$watchCollection('classes'` does not fire. Any suggestions?

```
  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Class</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-repeat="class in classes | orderBy">
        <input type="checkbox"
          ng-model="class.checked" >
        {{class.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

```
$scope.$watchCollection('classes', function(newValue) {
  console.log('sss')
});
```

Comment: i dont think $scope.classes going to change,then how $`watchCollection` will fire?

Comment: toggleing the checkbox sets the value with `ng-model="class.checked"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fixed your code, follow answer from @Sajeetharan for deep watch collection. But I think ng-change should be used in your case to capture event

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.checked" ng-change="chkChecked(class);"> {{class.description}}
```

Comment: ng-change is exactly what I ended  up using. I wasn't sure if it was against angular practices though.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a deepwatch in that case,

```
$scope.$watch(function($scope) {
      return $scope.classes.
      map(function(obj) {
        return obj.checked
      });
    }, function(newVal) {
      $scope.checked = true;
      alert("css chagned");
    }, true);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/2zypp97g/11/)

Comment: wouldn't `watchCollection` be doing the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Code goes here

angular
  .module('myApp', [])

.controller('testController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.classes = [{
      description: 'label1',
    }, {
      description: 'label2',
    }];

    $scope.$watch('classes', function(newValue) {
      console.log("watcher called");
    }, true);

  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="myApp">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body data-ng-controller="testController">

  <div class="filter-column">
    <div class="filter-title">Class</div>
    <div class="bottom-line"></div>
    <div class="overflow-container">
      <div ng-repeat="class in classes | orderBy">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.checked" ng-change="call(class)">{{class.description}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

$watch is able to get the changes.

Comment: see the reason why...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26393148/why-does-scope-watch-work-but-scope-watchcollection-does-not